# Flutter: FCM notification not working when app is in foreground

Tags: flutter

i'm using fcm api for push notification but can't received when app is in foreground, when app is in background it's working also notification comes silently in mobile device didn't pop up in mobile screen like other app.

```
getAllTokens.forEach((dynamic i) async {

      String url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
      final msg = jsonEncode({
        "to": i,
        "notification": {
          "body": "FCM test",
          "title": "FCM test",
          "sound": "default",
          "badge": "1"
        },

      });
      Map<String, String> headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'authorization':
            'key=<my_server_key>'
      };
      return await http
          .post(url, body: msg, headers: headers)
          .then((http.Response responce) {
        final int statusCode = responce.statusCode;
        if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400 || json == null) {
          throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
        } else {
          print("success");
        }
      });
    });
```